# Check mark and image next to mainMenu item

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, usability

I would like to be able to display an image and a check mark next to a menu item in a [mainMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mainmenu.aspx). Currently, it's either an image or a check mark, but I'm afraid both at the same time are not possible.

[image]

If I add `menuItemOption1.Checked = true;`, the item is checked but the image is not displayed anymore:

[image: Check mark]

I didn't find any other way to show the user that some menu item is checked (can't change the text color), can someone think of any way?

(I would like to keep the images displayed as my menu items have not-that-obvious names, and the images are a great way for the user to understand the menus.)

Comment: I think you should work with OwnerDrawn menu items. But it isn't an easy task - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw.aspx#Y505

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by changing simply the menu texts:

```
menuItemOption1.Text = "[✓] Option 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from the designer, but try adding this to your code:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)optionsMenu.DropDown).ShowCheckMargin = true;
  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)optionsMenu.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = true;
}
```

Comment: This works for a `menuStrip`, but not for a `mainMenu`: there is no `DropDown` property on a [`menuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.aspx).

Comment: @Otiel MainMenu objects don't have images, so you must be drawing it already aren't you?  MainMenu was replaced by MenuStrip.  Any reason not to use a MenuStrip?

Comment: I'm using [VistaMenu](http://wyday.com/vistamenu/) to add images to a `MainMenu` (but I believe, if you don't want to use any third-party tool, that adding images is as easy as adding an `ImageList` to the `mainMenu` - though I haven't tried it).

Comment: Didn't know that `MainMenu` was replaced by `MenuStrip`. I replaced my `MenuStrips` by `MainMenus` in order to follow the Windows look & feel, basically as explained in [this article](http://wyday.com/blog/2009/making-the-menus-in-your-net-app-look-professional/). Was that a mistake?

Comment: @Otiel Microsoft isn't helping you here.  The MenuStrip will render in its style, not in the operating system's style, whereas MainMenu will.  If it's that important, you have a lot of drawing to do.  :-(